# Loading fields with respect to select box content

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, jsp-tags

I have a JSP page and in that I am using Struts2 tags for making my registration form.
Now the first field is type which uses `s:select` tag. Now, depending on what is selected by the user I want to load next texfields on the same page below the select box. How can I do it? Here is my approach but it's not working.

```
<s:form action="clientAction" method="post">
  <s:select name="type" label="Registration Type" 
    list="{'Student','Faculty'}" emptyOption="false" />
  <s:if test="type.equals(Student)">        
    <s:textfield label="FirstName" name="s_fname"/>
    <s:textfield label="LastName" name="s_lname"/>
    <s:textfield label="UserName" name="s_username"/>
    <s:password label="Password" name="s_password"/>
    <s:textfield label="EmailId" name="s_email_id"/>
  </s:if>       
  <s:if test="type.equals(Faculty)">
    <s:textfield label="FirstName" name="fac_fname"/>
    <s:textfield label="LastName" name="fac_lname"/>
    <s:textfield label="UserName" name="fac_username"/>
    <s:password label="Password" name="fac_password"/>
    <s:textfield label="EmailId" name="fac_email"/>
    <s:textfield label="Course Name" name="course_name"/>
    <s:textfield label="Course Id" name="course_id"/>
  </s:if>
  <s:submit/>
</s:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with JQuery, and you don't need to *load* fields from the server, as well as mess up JavaScript code with JSP code. You should use `css_xhtml` theme to hide/show fields on change event of select box. Like in this example

```
<s:form action="clientAction" method="post" theme="css_xhtml">
    <s:select id="RegistrationType" name="type" label="Registration Type"
              list="{'Student', 'Faculty'}" emptyOption="false" />
  <s:div id="Student" cssStyle="display: none;">
    <s:textfield label="FirstName" name="s_fname"/>
    <s:textfield label="LastName" name="s_lname"/>
    <s:textfield label="UserName" name="s_username"/>
    <s:password label="Password" name="s_password"/>
    <s:textfield label="EmailId" name="s_email_id"/>
    <s:submit/>
  </s:div>

  <s:div id="Faculty" cssStyle="display: none;" >
    <s:textfield label="FirstName" name="fac_fname"/>
    <s:textfield label="LastName" name="fac_lname"/>
    <s:textfield label="UserName" name="fac_username"/>
    <s:password label="Password" name="fac_password"/>
    <s:textfield label="EmailId" name="fac_email"/>
    <s:textfield label="Course Name" name="course_name"/>
    <s:textfield label="Course Id" name="course_id"/>
    <s:submit/>
  </s:div>
</s:form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#RegistrationType').change(function(){
      $('#'+this.value).css('display', 'block');
      if (this.value=='Student') $('#Faculty').css('display', 'none');
      else $('#Student').css('display', 'none');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript's `onSelect` event on s:select tag to load the next fields in form depending upon the select of the "Registration Type".

```
<s:select onselect="loadForm();" name="type" label="Registration Type" list="{'Student','Faculty'}" emptyOption="false" />
```